Email Send using AWS SES in Laravel
I tried to send email using AWS SES SMTP and this is how I did.
.env
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=email-smtp.{AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME="${AWS_SES_USER_NAME}"
MAIL_PASSWORD="${AWS_SES_USER_PASS}"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

Code to send email
Mail::raw('This is email test', function ($email_message) {
    $email_message->from('FROM_EMAIL', 'FROM_NAME');
    $email_message->to('TO_EMAIL');
    $email_message->subject('Email Test');
    $email_message->setBody('This is email test', 'text/html');
});

After run above code, I got this error

TypeError: Symfony\Component\Mime\Message::setBody(): Argument #1 ($body) must be of type ?Symfony\Component\Mime\Part\AbstractPart, string given, called in E:\PetCheck\laravel-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php on line 23 in file E:\PetCheck\laravel-api\vendor\symfony\mime\Message.php on line 45

I am using Laravel 10 and AWS SES Sandbox account.
Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

If you insist on using Mail::raw(...), remove the commented line:
Mail::raw('This is email test', function ($email_message) {
    $email_message->from('${FROM_EMAIL}', '${FROM_NAME}');
    $email_message->to('${TO_EMAIL}');
    $email_message->subject('Email Test');
    //$email_message->setBody('This is email test', 'text/html');
});

HTML emails
Alternatively, you can use another syntax for html emails:
// Option 1
Mail::html('This is email test', function ($email_message) {
    $email_message->from('${FROM_EMAIL}', '${FROM_NAME}');
    $email_message->to('${TO_EMAIL}');
    $email_message->subject('Email Test');
});

// Option 2
Mail::send(['html' => new HtmlString('This is email test')], function ($email_message) {
    $email_message->from('${FROM_EMAIL}', '${FROM_NAME}');
    $email_message->to('${TO_EMAIL}');
    $email_message->subject('Email Test');
});

Recommended way
The more expressive and flexible option in Laravel 10 is to create a custom class for your mail:
php artisan make:mail TestEmail

<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Content;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Envelope;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class TestEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable;
    use SerializesModels;

    public function envelope(): Envelope
    {
        return new Envelope(
            from: new Address('${FROM_EMAIL}', '${FROM_NAME}'),
            subject: 'Email Test',
        );
    }

    public function content(): Content
    {
        return new Content(
            view: 'mails.test', // This is relative to resources/views by default
        );
    }
}

Send the email:
Mail::to('${TO_EMAIL}')->send(new TestEmail());

